# Error occurring while executing the jitsi-meet sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, jitsi, jitsi-meet

getting issues in executing the jitsi-meet sdk.
these are the issues occurring.

/Users/jeetk/Desktop/tring/iostring/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-jitsi-meet/Pods-jitsi-
meet.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "jitsi-meet" in project "app")

/Users/jeetk/Desktop/tring/iostring/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-jitsi-meet/Pods-jitsi-meet.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "jitsi-meet" in project "app")

/Users/jeetk/Desktop/tring/iostring/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-jitsi-meet/Pods-jitsi-meet.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "jitsi-meet" in project "app")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your implementation issue. Try to re-implement your **Jitsi-Meet** like this:

Using CocoaPods

The recommended way for using the SDK is by using `CocoaPods`. In order to do so, add the `JitsiMeetSDK` dependency to your existing Podfile or create a new one following this example:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

workspace 'JitsiMeetSDKTest.xcworkspace'

target 'JitsiMeetSDKTest' do
  project 'JitsiMeetSDKTest.xcodeproj'

  pod 'JitsiMeetSDK'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Replace JitsiMeetSDKTest with your project and target names.

Bitcode is not supported, so turn it off for your project.

The SDK uses Swift code, so make sure you select Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries in your project.

Since the SDK requests camera and microphone access, make sure to include the required entries for `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in your `Info.plist` file.

In order for app to properly work in the background, select the "audio" and "voip" background modes.

Last, since the SDK shows and hides the status bar based on the conference state, you may want to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to NO in your `Info.plist` file.

Follow this instruction properly: https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-ios-sdk

And I think you forgot to disable `Bitcode` from xcode.
[image]